# javamail imap SortTerm example

Tags: sorting, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to use `imapFolder.getSortedMessages(SortTerm[] term);` method to get mail and sorted by sent date.

```
public List<MailMessage> load(SortTerm[] term,)
        throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    List<MailMessage> mailMessages = new ArrayList<MailMessage>();
    term[0] = SortTerm.DATE;

    Store store = getStore();
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    if (folder != null) {
        IMAPFolder imapFolder = (IMAPFolder) folder;
        imapFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message[] messages = imapFolder.getSortedMessages(term);
        FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
        fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
        fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        folder.fetch(messages, fp);
        UIDFolder uidFolder = (UIDFolder) folder;

        for (Message message : messages) {
            Long uid = uidFolder.getUID(message);
            MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) message;
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(msg, uid);
            mailMessages.add(mailMessage);
        }
    }

    return mailMessages;
}
```

but it not work for me.It don't sort by sent date.
Any suggestion for my program.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?  Do you get back all the messages in the folder?  Are they in message number order or some other order?  What does the session debug output show?

Comment: get back all the messages in the folder.

Comment: Are you sure the mail server you are contacting supports the SORT extension - RFC 5256 @wilson ?